# Laravel search not working. this part does not seem to work "->where('forms.Doc_Desc','LIKE','%'.$query.'%') "

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make a search box. Merged 5 tables, works properly in my index.

This is my search function

```
public function search(Request $request) {
    $query = $request['query'];
    $Rates =  DB::table('rates')
        ->join('forms', 'forms.id' ,'=', 'rates.FormID') 
        ->join('documents', 'documents.FormID', '=', 'rates.formID')
        ->join('contractors', 'contractors.user_id', '=', 'rates.contractor_id')        
        ->join('countries', 'countries.ID', '=', 'forms.country')->orwhere('documents.Status', '=', '2')->orwhere('documents.Status', '=', '4')->where('forms.Doc_Desc','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')   
        ->get(['rates.Class', 'rates.Rate', 'rates.Rate2','forms.Doc_Desc','documents.FileName', 'documents.Status', 'countries.country', 'contractors.contractor_name'])->groupBy('Doc_Desc')->map(function ($Rate, $key) { return $Rate;});
 
     if (count($Rates) > 0)   {
      return view('admin.rates',[
        'Rates' => $Rates,
      ]);
     }
     else {
      return back()->withInput()->with('status','No Luck');
     }
   }
```

This is my View

```
 @foreach( $Rates as $Rate=>$ID)
     <tr>
        <td> 
            @foreach($ID as $IDs)  
                {{$IDs->contractor_name }} 
                @break 
            @endforeach 
        </td>
                                            
        <td> {{ $Rate}} </td> 
        <td> 
            @foreach($ID as $IDs)   
                @if ($IDs->Class == 'Metro') 
                    {{$IDs->Rate }} + {{$IDs->Rate2 }}
                    <small class="text-warning">*</small>   
                    @break  
                @endif   
            @endforeach
        </td>
        <td> 
            @foreach($ID as $IDs)   
                  @if ($IDs->Class == 'Regional') {{$IDs->Rate }}  + {{$IDs->Rate2 }}<small class="text-warning">*</small> 
                  @break 
                  @endif  
                                                                      
             @endforeach
         </td>
         <td> 
             @foreach($ID as $IDs)  
                 @if ($IDs->Class == 'Remote') {{$IDs->Rate }} + {{$IDs->Rate2 }}<small class="text-warning">*</small>  
                 @break   
                 @endif  
             @endforeach
          </td>   
          <td> 
          @foreach($ID as $IDs)  
              @if ($IDs->Class != 'Metro' && $IDs->Class != 'Regional' && $IDs->Class != 'Remote') <span class="badge badge-secondary">  {{$IDs->Class }}  </span>  
              @endif  
          @endforeach     
         </td>
```

I have two different routes created(one for the plain view and another for the search(with different URIs)
it's really messy. im new and hoping someone can help. Thank You!

also added this above my table  @if(isset($Rates))

Comment: you should better use models instead of making join functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way you are using your `where` and `orwhere` clauses:

```
->orwhere('documents.Status', '=', '2')
->orwhere('documents.Status', '=', '4')
->where('forms.Doc_Desc','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
```

If one of those is true it will return you the result without filtering it, so for example if your status is 2 then no matter your `$query` variable, the result will be returned.

What you need to do is you have to encapsulate the 2 `orwhere` clauses into one `where` clause and let the filtering `where` stand alone or for your example simply use `whereIn`.

For example:

```
 ->where('forms.Doc_Desc','LIKE','%'.$query.'%') 
 ->where(function ($q) {
           $q->where('documents.Status', '=', '2')
             ->orwhere('documents.Status', '=', '4')
            
    })
```

Or even simpler which will work for your code

```
 ->whereIn('documents.Status',[2,4])
 ->where('forms.Doc_Desc','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
```